# Can't load delimitedtext layer

Tags: pyqgis, csv, qgsvectorlayer

I am on Linux Debian with Python

```
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
```

Here is my code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os

from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr/lib/qgis/", True)

# Initialisation de QGIS
app = QgsApplication([], False)
app.initQgis()

# Obtention de l'instance du projet
monProjet = QgsProject.instance()

mypath = os.path.join('/home/toto/', 'myfile.csv')
options = '?delimiter=;&detectTypes=yes&wktField=WKT&crs=EPSG:4326'

uri = 'file://{}{}'.format(mypath, options)

maCouche = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'my info', 'delimitedtext')
if not maCouche.isValid():
    print("La couche segments_wkt n'a pas pu être chargée !")
else:
    monProjet.addMapLayer(maCouche)
```

- Whatever y try, I get : "La couche segments_wkt n'a pas pu être chargée !".
- `maCouche.isValid()` give me `False`, but I don't know why it is false.
- I can open my delimitedtext file as layer with QGIS 3.28.
- I can execute this code on Windows 10 with Python 3.9.5 that comes with QGIS 3.28.

How can I investigate?
Is there another method?

Comment: what's the value of `uri` ?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your CSV file?

Comment: @bugmenot123 I wonder wether my comment was ambiguous. I meant : "I have added the samples in the initial request". I apologize for my english.

Comment: @IanTurton I wonder wether my comment was ambiguous. I meant : "I have added the samples in the initial request". I apologize for my english.

Comment: @Kadir sorry, I can't share the whole csv, but the sample csv file gives the same result as the whole file.

Comment: Can you edit and just keep the [minimal code needed to reproduce the error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?